# Alembic detects changes but produces empty migration with --autogenerate

Tags: python, mysql, migration, sqlalchemy, alembic

I'm trying to get alembic working auto-producing migrations with the `--autogenerate` flag.

When I run `alembic -n mydbname --autogenerate -m "my message"` I get something like:

```
INFO  [alembic.migration] Context impl MySQLImpl.
INFO  [alembic.migration] Will assume non-transactional DDL.
INFO  [alembic.autogenerate] Detected removed table u'some_table'
INFO  [alembic.autogenerate] Detected NULL on column 'table_a.column_a'
INFO  [alembic.autogenerate] Detected added column 'table_b.column_b'
.......
```

but then when I look at the migration file that is generated, `upgrade` and `downgrade` both simply say `pass`.

What's going on?!

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the multi-db migrations?  If so, they're currently a bit buggy.  The solution is to change your context.configure in env.py to look something like:

```
context.configure(
    connection=rec['connection'],
    upgrade_token="%s_upgrades" % name,
    downgrade_token="%s_downgrades" % name,
    target_metadata=target_metadata.get(name)
)
```

([source](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.sqlalchemy.alembic/9))